# Integrating the step-wise integer function 1/[x]

Tags: calculus, integration, integer-programming

I'm trying to find the integral, respective to $x$, of a function that utilizes the step-wise integer (or floor) function.

$$\displaystyle z = \int {1 \over [[x]*1.1^{[y]}]+1}$$

It's for modelling a game simulation, but it's more of a math than programming question. I'm confused because there isn't exactly a direct correlation between an integral for a regular function of x and an integer[x] function of x.

For example, the integral of $[x]$ is $ \displaystyle ([x]^2-[x])\over 2$ (which is the summation).

I know that the integral of $1/x$ is $ln(x)$, but it isn't straightforward for $1/[x]$. I mean- it seems like the integral of the harmonic series, $ln(x+1)$, should be my starting point (since this is a general harmonic series)- but the corresponding table doesn't work out.

It doesn't even work out for $1/x$ in a way that makes any sense to me- IE, $1/1+1/2 = 3/2 \not= ln(2+1)$

Under normal integration rules I should get this (i think)- $\displaystyle \frac{ln([[x]*1.1^{[y]}]+1)} {1.1^{[y]}} + C$, but it doesn't line up. I need to make a pretty 3d-graph, so generating a summation table for salient values of $x$ ($1$ to $20$ or so) isn't helpful (at least- my 3d grapher won't smooth it). How can I accurately represent this as a function for graphing purposes? Any recommended software?

Or am I going in completely the wrong direction? IS this not an integration problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability if you format your questions using [*MathJax*](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Thanks

Comment: Oh thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the floor will convert the integral to a sum, as you hint at in your question, because the function will be constant over a unit range of $x$.  So assuming $a,b$ naturals, $\int_a^b \frac 1{\lfloor x \rfloor} dx=\sum_{i=a}^{b-1} \frac 1i=H_{b-1}-H_{a-1}$ where the $H$'s are [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  In two dimensions the same thing happens:  each square has the floors of $x$ and $y$ fixed, so you can just compute the value and sum all those.  If your boundary doesn't follow lattice lines, you have to figure out how much of each square is included.

Comment: Firstly, Is there software that will model a series in 3D?

Secondly, when calculating the integer function, we're basically creating a function that jags between two curves- 1/x and 1/(x-1). Would it make sense to integrate each one separately, take the difference, and add it to the integration of the original? I tried this, but the results don't seem right.

Comment: @marco:  I know Mathematica and I suspect Maple will sum or integrate over both $x$ and $y$.  Since $\lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le \lceil x \rceil$ you can bound the integral between $\ln \frac ba$ and $\ln \frac {b-1}{a-1}$.  Essentially one is the lower Riemann sum and the other is the upper.

Comment: Oh- I don't need to integrate Y, only X- I just need to be able to model the equation in 3-dimensions. That is, I need the integral of the equation relative to X for every possible Y. Where X >= 1 and Y >= 0. I'll need to look into those Riemann sums to see if that helps- thanks for your advice!